# GoDaddy domain on AWS for S3 bucket, HOW?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

So I have been trying to figure out how to get my GoDaddy domain to link with my static S3 bucket so that I can host a static website using my domain.

The only guides I could find were for an Amazon hosted domain which I do not have.

I tried to figure out how hosted zones work and perhaps its my little understanding that is running me into road blocks trying to figure that out.

Do I use go daddy's nameservers and create a hosted zone record?  I am very lost here and google is getting me nowhere.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The problem is going to be working out what the A records should be for your domain, and that's possibly something only Amazon's DNS system will know.

Comment: [This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) says under 'Alias Target' you should set your domain to point to one of the [Amazon S3 Website Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints) - but you can't use CNAME aliases for the root domain, which is why Amazon have their own 'alias' mechanism where they can reply with an up-to-date IP address for the S3 endpoint, possibly even the right geographic one, because they know all of those IP addresses themselves.

Comment: You just need to point your domain to AWS name server or please just point your A record to AWS IP address in order to host your domain.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here was the AWS guide was incomplete.

Also that I had changed the nameservers on the hosted zone in AWS.

If anyone is reading this, DO NOT CHANGE THE NS record ON THE HOSTED ZONE.